# Understanding the use of Flow debounce operator

Tags: android, kotlin

Following some suggestions and doing some personal research - I did a tiny project (not of any significance) of my own to reflect the concept I have learned.

**What is the project?**

A Slider component with a Text component to its right. The text component shows the real-time value of the Slider component.

In the next row - there is another text field which displays the value of slider multiplied by three. Just for the sake of extreme simplicity - let's assume that multiplying something by the 3 is a complicated process - LOL.

**What I am expecting?**

The second text component will update only after the user has stopped interacting with the Slider.

**What I am seeing?**

The second text component is updating along with the first one - even though I have given debounce value of 2000L.

**The code for ViewModel class:**

```
class WhatWeSeeViewModel : ViewModel () {

    private val _sliderValue = MutableStateFlow(8)
    val sliderValue
        get() = _sliderValue.asStateFlow()
    
    val valueAfterCalculations
        get() = _sliderValue
            .debounce(2000L)
            .stateIn(
                viewModelScope,
                SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
                _sliderValue.value * 3
            )

    fun updateSliderValue (value: Int) {
        _sliderValue.value = value

    }

}
```

**The code for the Composable function:**

```
@Composable
fun WhatWeSee(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: WhatWeSeeViewModel = androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel()
) {
    val sliderValue = viewModel.sliderValue.collectAsState().value
    val textValue = viewModel.valueAfterCalculations.collectAsState().value

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Slider(
                modifier = modifier.weight(1f),
                value = sliderValue.toFloat(),
                onValueChange = {viewModel.updateSliderValue(it.toInt())},
                valueRange = 4f..50f
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

            Text(
                text = sliderValue.toString(),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall,
            )
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

        Text(
            text = textValue.toString(),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge
        )
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Combining a custom getter `get()` with `stateIn` means it’s creating a new copy of the hot flow every time the property is accessed. That is a resource leak. Not related to issue you’re describing, though. At least I don’t think so.

Comment: Actually it could be the source of your issue. Every time the Composable recomposes, it will be getting a new copy of the state flow, so it doesn’t think it’s looking at the same thing any more and will refresh needlessly. If that’s the case you also need to get rid of the `get()` for the `asStateFlow()` also.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Remove `get()` from your code.

**Explanation**

`valueAfterCalculations` is defined as the result from the *function* (not *value*) that comes after `get()`. The function always returns what the following produces (I took the liberty to add parameter names to the `stateIn` function):

```
_sliderValue
    .debounce(2000L)
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        initialValue = _sliderValue.value * 3,
    )
```

Now, whenever `valueAfterCalculations` is read (that happens on every recomposition, in this case every time the slider is moved), the `get()` function is executed. That is the entire code block above: A new flow is created based on `_sliderValue` and debounced by 2000ms, then it is converted to a state flow with the initial value of the mutable slider flow multiplied by 3. As soon as the sider value is changes, all of this is thrown away and the steps are repeated, so a lot of new flows are created (not new values of the flow) and the `debounce` never comes into play.

What you actually want is that the variable `valueAfterCalculations` is defined by executing the above block *once*. And that's done by simply assigning it to the variable, no `get()` shenanigans necessary.

As a side note: Although your calculation (the multiplication by 3) is only done with the `initialValue` of the state flow, it seemed to work since it was executed for every value, because you created an entire new flow for each value. So, if you fix your flow, the calculation has to be moved to somewhere where it actually is executed every time the flow *emits* a new value, not when it is created. Possibly like this:

```
_sliderValue
    .debounce(2000L)
    .map { it * 3 }
    .stateIn(
        scope = viewModelScope,
        started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        initialValue = _sliderValue.value
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. So, why is get() still a thing in Kotlin ?

Comment: Think of it as a getter function, like in Java. There are useful scenarios where you want to calculate something but don't want to expose it as a function, but as a property. For more info see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html